# How to save result of executing command in link server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distributed-transactions

I need to execute same command in different server using linked-server.

```
INSERT #Result
EXEC ('command') AT @linked_server
```

Because Insert statement opens an Implicit transaction and I can not enable DTC(Distributed transaction control) the following error will occur:

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
> "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "RM-BIEDW" was unable to begin a
> distributed transaction.

Is there any solution other than enabling DTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn of 'remote proc transaction promotion', eg

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'linked_server', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
```

Or use OPENQUERY

```
insert #result 
select * from openquery(linked_server, 'command')
```

Comment: Your answer is acceptable. My first choice was OPENQUERY but the reason I switch to EXEC AT was the limitation of command length. Finally I used OPENUERY and minimized my query.